# Close event on NamedPipeClientStream when the server closes the pipe

Tags: c#, windows

I am using `NamedPipeClientStream` to communicate with a server which is running locally. Is there a way I can register for Close event so that I can get notified when the server closes the pipe?

The requirement is that I need to again establish connection and keep waiting for the server to come up so that I can connect to it quickly.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to know when the local pipe object itself is closed? Or do you want to know when the remote endpoint of the pipe is closed, signaling end-of-stream? For either, your code should already be in complete control of and complete awareness of those occurrences, so it should be trivial for you to implement code that raises an event if either happens. **What have you tried**?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Its within my control if it was the local pipe object on the client. My question is regarding the server end of the pipe. When the pipe on the remote endpoint is closed, I would like to receive notification. I don't need a solution where server sends a message which indicates close to all the client so that client can process it. The scenario which I want to handle is when the server process gets terminated abruptly, I would like receive some sort of event/notification so that I can wait on the server to connect immediately.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I noticed that even the ongoing Read call will not throw IOException with "Pipe is broken". It just returns without reading any data.

Comment: after you connect - you need just call [`BeginRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipestream.beginread?view=netframework-4.8), and from [`AsyncCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.asynccallback?view=netframework-4.8) - if no error - call `BeginRead` again and so on. when you got error - this mean server disconnect or close it end

Comment: *It just returns without reading any data*

Comment: @HansPassant. Have you highlighted whatever I wrote in my comment as a response to @RbMm or you are telling that `Read()` returning without any data should be the condition to safely assume that the pipe is closed/broken.

Comment: Just emphasizing the solution you already found by yourself.  When Read() completes without returning any data then you know that it concluded that no data will be forthcoming.  Because the opposite end got closed.